# Angular - Setting form element to invalid from directive not invalidating form

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that handles password requirements. The password needs to be validated on keyup so that each regex can be evaluated and updated in a popover as the user inputs characters. When I set the input element to $invalid if any of the regex fails the form itself is not invalidated. I'm using `form.$invalid` to disable the submit button.

**Controller form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" 
      ng-submit="vm.createUserForm.$valid && vm.createUser(newUser)"
      role="form" name="vm.createUserForm" id="create-user-form"
      novalidate>
  <label for="new-user-password">Password</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <password-validation form-model="vm.createUserForm">
      </password-validation>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1- col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button ng-disabled="vm.createUserForm.$invalid" 
              class="btn btn-primary" 
              type="submit">
        Create User
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Password directive**

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('fotaAdminPortal')
.directive('passwordValidation', function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      formModel: '='
    },
    template: '<input required autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" type="password" class="form-control" id="new-user-password" name="newUserPassword" ng-model="newUser.password" required ng-keyup="validatePassword()" popover-animation="false" popover-is-open="showPasswordPopover" uib-popover-template="\'components/directives/password-validation.tpl.html\'">',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.passwordLengthError = true;
      scope.passwordDigitError = true;
      scope.passwordSpecialError = true;
      scope.passwordUpperError = true;
      scope.passwordLowerError = true;
      scope.showPasswordPopover = false;
      scope.formModel.newUserPassword.$validators.validPassword = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;
        var regexDigit = /\d/;
        var regexSpecial = /[!@#$%^&*]/;
        var regexUpper = /(?=.*[A-Z])/;
        var regexLower = /(?=.*[a-z])/;
        if(value !== undefined) {
          if (value.length < 8) {
            scope.passwordLengthError = true;
          } else {
            scope.passwordLengthError = false;
          }
          if (!regexDigit.test(value)) {
            scope.passwordDigitError = true;
          } else {
            scope.passwordDigitError = false;
          }
          if (!regexSpecial.test(value)) {
            scope.passwordSpecialError = true;
          } else {
            scope.passwordSpecialError = false;
          }
          if (!regexUpper.test(value)) {
            scope.passwordUpperError = true;
          } else {
            scope.passwordUpperError = false;
          }
          if (!regexLower.test(value)) {
            scope.passwordLowerError = true;
          } else {
            scope.passwordLowerError = false;
          }
          if(!scope.passwordLengthError && !scope.passwordDigitError && !scope.passwordSpecialError && !scope.passwordUpperError && !scope.passwordLowerError) {
            scope.showPasswordPopover = false;
            return true;
          } else {
            scope.showPasswordPopover = true;
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false; // shouldn't 'required' on template handle this?
        }
      };

    } // link
  };
});

})();
```

Comment: Normally directives add custom validators to the `ngModelController.$validators` object. Then the FormController will be automatically updated. For more information, see [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference -- $validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code above which seems to be working, however, why do I need to return false if value is undefined? Shouldn't adding 'required' to the template handle this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.